# Firebase Analytics not showing the latest release

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-ios, firebase-analytics

I am working with an iOS/Android react-native app, month ago i launched the 1.5.0 version but in firebase analytics "latest release" it only shows the 1.3.0.
All my users already update the app so i dont have any new data.

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the issue downloading again the configuration files:

- Android: google-services.json.
- iOS: GoogleService-Info.plist.

Comment: Did you release another version to Playstore with new googleservice json to make analytics show new latest version ?

Comment: No, just interacting with your device/emulator should update analytics latest version. @NavinSamuel

Answer (score 1):

Check your GoogleService-Info.plist

```
IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED
```